# Convert dynamic to object from dapper Query<dynamic>

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, dapper

Is it possible to convert dynamic variable returned from Dapper.Query to object? Example:

```
class MyClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<dynamic> data = sql.Query<dynamic>(SELECT * FROM MyClassTable");
foreach(var record in data)
{
    int parent_id = record.SomeId;
    // any simple way to fill MyClass properites from record?
    // instead of doing in manually?
    MyClass obj = ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any simple way to fill MyClass properites from record?
>        instead of doing in manually?

No. Unfortunately you'll have to do it manually. The best thing you can do is move the mapping logic to one place so you can re-use it in your data access layer. I usually use extension methods, but you can also use reflection to set matching property names...however, in my personal opinion, I usually use dapper for its performance benefits and using reflection is a bit expensive, for that reason I usually avoid using reflection in these cases.

> Is it possible to convert dynamic variable returned from Dapper.Query to object?

Yes. As explained above

I know you probably wanted to simplify your question but I guess it's worth pointing out that the example that you posted doesn't need to return a dynamic object if `MyClass` represents the records returned by that select query. You could simply do the following...

```
var data = sql.Query<MyClass>(SELECT * FROM MyClassTable");
```

Comment: Yes, but I have additional parameters in MyClassTable (SomeId in example) that I want to process. I am aware of MultiMapping but I do not want to use it in this case.